# Multisite Login Access Restrictions

Tags: multisite, users, user-access, content-restriction

I am building a multisite where users can sign up to create a subsite about there business. I would like to have them be able to login to the backend and edit there subsite but restrict them from accessing any other subsite or main site. Is there a function that can help me with this?

Comment: users are already unable to edit sites they don't have a role on, can you be more specific? I edited out the part about asking if there is a plugin as that would have gotten your question closed as offtopic, you can't ask for recommendations here

Comment: Thank you I did not realize that was a native feature, and appreciate the edits!